# How can I set default value of PGD/PGC pin of Snap programmer?

Tags: debugging, microcontroller, mplab

I use Snap programmer and MPLAB X IDE v5.40. After programming of target device, programming pins PGD/PGC are set to high level (Supply voltage). Is it possible to set programming pins to low level (Ground voltage) before start of program? If it is possible, how could i make this settings?

Comment: What does the protocol documentation say? Is it possible that these levels are required as the final state? -- What does the documentation to Snap and the IDE say?